# Access groups and reports of power bi through Postman

Tags: powerbi, postman

I am getting an access token through post man as shown from image below [image]

Unless the scope is wrong which i think is not i should be able to access reports and groups of power BI, just by passing the generated token as header in the request
After passing the token i get 403 I am not sure what is wrong with my request although i do know 403 means some rights are missing.
Any suggestions ? Thank you

[image]

Now i am getting this 
[image]
This is what i think might be the issue but i am not sure, ConsentType :AllPrinciapls

Answer (score 2):

The bearer token requires an access token, not the client secret. You need register a Native app rather than a server-side web app for Power BI Embedded cases and grant sufficient permissions.

[Register App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/register-app)

[Granting Permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/register-app#apply-permissions-to-your-application-within-azure-ad)

Then to get the access token, you can call the POST API in POSTMAN as

```
POST /common/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: login.windows.net
Cache-Control: no-cache 
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id={client id}&grant_type=password&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fanalysis.windows.net%2Fpowerbi%2Fapi&username={your power bi account}&password={your Power BI password}
```

[image]

So that you can call you can call the [GenerateToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/embedtoken) API.

At last you can call Reports. Example is given [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/getreportsingroup)

Ref Question and it's answer: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Developer/Power-BI-REST-API-using-postman-generate-embed-token/td-p/310054

Comment: So the first POST request /common/oauth2/token generates token but we cant use this token to access reports ?

Comment: If so then next we perform POST https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{groupId}/dashboards/{dashboardId}/GenerateToken but how can i get group id and dashboard id ? What do we use the first token generated for  ? @AnkUser

Comment: i am getting The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID '8037b3e0-sdffds-43fa-b4d8-78b22a22ce1d' named 'SYSTEMClient'. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.\r\nTrace ID: 7b1e6bce-229d-450b-90cc-b522dd354800\r\nCorrelation ID: 3c67782f-4d19-4097-9bc6-636b75012317\r\nTimestamp: 2019-09-03 05:39:53Z",
    "error_codes": [

Comment: What about redirect URisl should i set this to https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient

Comment: @valik if you publish your report to PowerBi online in your enviornment, you will get Group Id and Report Id as well.
W.r.t redirect uri you can give as you wish there is no restriction.
what exactly is blocking you now? I believe if you follow the links and tutorials mentioned you should be able to access report using Postman!!

Comment: thank you for your response , I posted my error now i think its about consent. I think Admin user need to send a request to change consent type to all principals. Also im not sure after i get this token do i put it in the authorisation header and make a request to get groups ?

Comment: you need to login to portal.azure.com then look for your App which you registered and when you see API permission at the very bottom you will find "Grant Admin consent for xyz.." you need to click it (if you are admin or else ask admin) and then you will be able to perform your operations