# Unable to get Azure Oauth2 token

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I am unable to get Azure Oauth2 authorization token on a government cloud tenant. I keep getting the following error response:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "AADSTS50126: Invalid username or password.\r\nTrace ID: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx\r\nCorrelation ID: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx\r\nTimestamp: 2019-09-15 00:00:00Z",
    "error_codes": [
        50126
    ],
    "timestamp": "2019-09-15 00:00:00Z",
    "trace_id": "xxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "correlation_id": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "error_uri": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=50126"
}
```

I am using following information in the post call:

```
End Point: 
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<Tenant Id>/oauth2/v2.0/token

Headers: 
Content-Type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: application/json

Body:
client_id : <client id>
client_secret: <client secret>
grant_type: password
username: <username>
password: <password>
scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
```

Comment: I answered similar question, did you tried steps mentioned in here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57754463/5436880

Answer (score 0):

Very close but you are not using the correct endpoint, try using this:

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TenantID/DirectoryID}/oauth2/token`

vs

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/<Tenant Id>/oauth2/v2.0/token`

Comment: I updated the endpoint to https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TenantID}/oauth2/token but I got a different error response:

"error": "invalid_request",
    "error_description": "AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'resource' ....

Comment: After adding resource: https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api  to body, I got the same error again: 

"error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "AADSTS50126: Invalid username or password.

Comment: Reset the password on the account you are trying to use and try again. 50126 means the username or password is wrong so I'm assuming its the password but maybe it is your username. Basically verify 100% the credentials are correct before investigating further.

Comment: Easy test would be to try and log in to powerbi.com with the account. Also if its not a valid power bi account with license that could also explain the error.

Comment: Make sure you are sending the parameters as form content. The authority in the question is correct.